# MVC Application design with Submit and Sort Functionality for each account entity listing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For my MVC project, I have accounts details to be listed in a account card format as in the picture below:

[image]

1. Each Accounts metadata in the account card is coming from database and each card can have fields like Dropdowns, Textboxes, etc.
2. Each Account Card will have a **SUBMIT** Functionality to post the data related to that account card with client side validation for few fields.
3. The Main Form will have a Exclusive **SUBMIT ALL** Button to post data for a set of Account Cards. May be we will put a check-box against each Account Card on which Submit ALL would work on.
4. There will be Sort Functionality at the top to sort the Account Cards based on Name and Price Value

The challenge is the application will have two user roles ADMIN and NORMAL-USER. Submit buttons inside the Account cards would be available only for ADMIN Role.

How should I design the application to hide and show the Submit Buttons or enable/disable few fields in the account card based on the user role? Should I use a partial view form for each Account Card. If I use a Partial View Form then how **Submit ALL** button and **Sort Drop-down** would function.

If any guidance can be offered for the best approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you have your view bound to a model that has a list of AccountDisplayModels. These of course will be based on your AccountModel, with properties removed/added to fit the display (a typical view model). The model should also include a flag for displaying the account for an admin or not based on the user role. In the view you perform a `For Each` on that list. For each account you display it as you see fit based on the user role flag that was set when building your model.

For the individual submit buttons, you can attach a JavaScript to them (based on a class you give them while creating them). By using simple naming conventions either on the `Div`'s that contain each account's fields or the fields themselves, your script can iterate over the fields and submit only the fields for that card. The submit all button can iterate over the cards (again based on a naming conventions for the `DIV`s) and check for the value of the checkboxes (if you decide to implement that feature) and then submit the cards either to the same action method that receives the single card (in that case the single card case would have a list of one card) or to another one altogether. You can have different submit buttons on a form call different action methods with the use of `ActionNameAttribute` and an implementation of `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`.

As for sorting, you can use a JavaScript library that can do that for you on the client side (not sure which is best for this but I am sure someone can suggest a good library), or send a query to the server with the sort parameter(s) which would return a differently sorted list as appropriate.

**EDIT**

Assume that your `AccountModel` represents the domain model that reflects the database and it has 20 fields. Of those you display 3 in the card. In your Model Building class you would have something like:

```
var accounts = MyDataAccessObject.RetrieveAccounts(criteriaICareAbout);
var displayCards = accounts.Select(c => new AccountDisplayModel
                                         {
                                             x = c.AccountNumber
                                             y = c.AccountName,
                                             z = c.Status
                                             // other fields that relate to each card
                                         });
//You can always use something like AutoMapper to replace the Select command above.
var viewModel = new ViewModelForCardsView{
                                             accountsList = displayCards,
                                             showAdminFields = IsUserAnAdmin()
                                             //Other fields that apply to the whole view
                                         }
```

In the view you would do something along the lines of:

```
foreach (var card in Model.accountsList){
    // create div for card
    // create fields for both types of users
    if(showAdminFields){
        //create fields shown to admin alone
        //create input of type button 
        //Attach to the button an OnClick event handler to call the 
        //JavaScript function that handles submission and pass it a parameter
        //allowing it to identify which Div/fields to capture 
    }
}
```

I hope that I have understood your questions properly and that I have addressed them.

**EDIT2**

A great option that provide sorting/filtering capabilities are ListView controls that allow you to display information in the format that you want based on templates that you create. These controls require a bit more setup and take some learning but still easier than implementing the sorting filtering by hand. 
If you still want to implement the view as I have outlined above, it would be one view with each card displayed in it's own Div element and not a partial view. The sorting can be then done by having the dropdown fire a request to the server (can be AJAX to improve performance) with the same search criteria that retrieved the page as well as the desired sorting field. The controller would sort the list according to the new order field and rebuild the view.

**EDIT3**

Glad to be of help. The answers to your comments are turning out to be long so I am including them as edits :)

You can definitely add client side validation. There are some standard ones that can be added to the model (either statically or even dynamically) what is even more, you can have even the custom validation on the server propagated automatically to the client, thus having both validations. That is a whole long topic on its own but have a look at ValidationAttribute for the standard ones and you can write your own that implement IClientValidatable in order to propagate them to the client

As for submission, you can use $.ajax. Here is a skeleton code you can adapt:

```
var methodUrl = '@Url.Action("GetMenuComponents", "Request")';
var methodParam = JSON.stringify(//The parameter's list goes here); 
var successMethod = function (srvResponse) {
                if (srvResponse) {
                    $("#Div_Cards").html(srvResponse);
                }
            };
$.ajax({
    type: requestType, // GET or POST
    url: methodUrl ,
    data: methodParam ,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: dataType, //html for methods that return partial views
    processData: false,
    success: successMethod,
    error: OnError});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply to my problem. You mean the submit functionalities should be handled via JQuery/Javascript posting events by capturing the data using fields' HTML IDs/Classes. One more concern is would you suggest to avoid Partial view for each Account card keeping in consideration the Sorting/Any filtering option functionality that I need on the main page.  How should I populate the account cards each with a submit button on the main page? (The Entire Accounts metadata is coming from the Database)

Comment: Yes you understood me properly regarding the capturing of the field's value through their ids. Not sure what you mean with the concern regarding sorting/filtering and how it relates to the partial views. I will try to include some pseudo code to illustrate filling the view model based on the data retrieved from the database.

Comment: Ok.Let me illustrate a bit. If you see the image in my question above, I have list of Accounts Cards(formatted HTML for each account, the 'boxed' view) displayed, each having a SUBMIT button.So my question is how should I bring these account cards on main page. Should I keep each box in a partial view and then render them, or, something else? As the ultimate goal is to have the sort functionality on these cards as well based on , say, Account Name.  Later down the line, I need to incorporate a filter functionality, say via a dropdown on the main page to filter Accounts on, say, 'REGION'.

Comment: Thanks a ton @JTMon. Understood entirely, so you probably mean to keep a Strongly-typed view on the lines of e.g. IENUMERABLE<Account> and hide/ show content based on with ROLE flag present in the model object. One last thing, Can I implement some client side validation on few fields on each Account card when user click of the Submit button which is present within the account card? I am little confused on this part as you said Submit will be Ajax-based post. A little example will help a lot

Comment: Ahh, Sorry but I was aware of this part. But guess could not made my concern clear. To make things simpler for myself, suppose I get the Account Card's formatted HTML (with fields and submit button) from server itself, so essentially I am talking about without keeping IEnumerable<Account> model on the view. Can I add Client-side validation on each Card on click of submit button. I am aware of Client-side validation attributes provided by MVC like Required but since I will not be having any model in such implementation, how to add rules to fields when user click Submit.Is there any way out??

Comment: I really think you are staring to mix things up and get away from MVC. The Html returned from server is generated by the view which is bound to the model which would have the attributes, which gets propagated to the client.

Comment: Yes, in a way I am doing away with MVC by following this away which is bad. I could not explain here why I am doing it like this. I have created another question in the same context if you can have a look, why I am doing it this way. Sorry for bothering so much. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708413/client-side-validation-on-listboxes-mvc-view

Answer (score 1):

You need to create 2 partial views for admin and normal user. In user partial view just comment the parts you don't want. in login page get the information about the user with session and send it to the view to decide which partial to return

---

look one of my codes in a project

```
<div class="widget-body">
                        <!--begin blog post-->
                        @foreach(var item in Model._myMood)
                        {

                            //string isLike = @ViewData["isLike"].ToString();
                            string isLike = " ";
                            string like = " ";
                            //string isLike = @ViewData["isLike"].ToString();
                            if (Model._myLike.Contains(item.id))
                            {
                                isLike = "red";
                                like = "Liked";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                isLike = " ";
                                like = "Like";
                            }

                        <div class="row-fluid blog">
                            <div class="span4">
                                <img src="~/Content/moods/@item.moodType" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span8">
                                <div class="date">
                                    <p class="day">@item.day</p>
                                    <p class="month">@item.month.ToString("MMMM")</p>
                                </div>
                                <h2>
                                    <a href="blog_details.html">@item.userName feels @item.moodType</a>
                                </h2>
                                <p>
                                    By <a href="javascript:;">@item.userName</a>
                                </p>
                                <p style="word-wrap:break-word">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.moodReason)
                                    </p>
                                <ul style="height:20px">
                                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Comment", new { id = item.id })"><i class="icon-comments-alt"></i> (@item.commentCount) Comments</a></li>
                                    <li>@using (Html.BeginForm()){ <a href="@Url.Action("Liked","MyMoods",new {id = item.id})" style="color:@isLike"><i class="icon-heart @isLike"></i> @like </a>}</li>
                                    <li style="margin-left:-10px">@using(Html.BeginForm()){<a>(@item.likeCount)</a>}</li>
                                    @*<li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="icon-share"></i> 34 Shares</a></li>*@
                                </ul>
                                @*<a href="blog_details.html" class="btn btn-info">Continue Reading</a>*@
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        }

                        <!--end blog post-->

                    </div>
```

the "isLike" in there is a css class I used that for class attribute as you see and look at my if clause I am checking a data for each of my items you will design yours.

Comment: But then how will 'Sort' and 'Submit All' will behave on data present in partial view? Moreover, each Account-Card will have Submit functionality. How will the Partial view be loaded with 'N' number of accounts in the database with Submit Button in each?

Comment: oh if I understood right then you can define a class in your css as {display:none} and if the account datas are admin you will give the buttons class name that you define in css if not you wont give

Comment: This ROLE information will be coming from Database. How can a CSS class be added or removed in the view based on database flag. Also, you mean to display all account Cards in single partial view, then how Sort and Submit ALL will work across all account cards.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. I got the idea. The other part of the problem is if you mean to keep all account Cards in single partial view how will Sort and Submit ALL will work across all account cards in that case.